# codeigniter resize image by width

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a new photo using dynamic width only so that the Height then changes depending on the width automatically.

The following code is not working with me.

```
$w = $width;
$w = $w / 4 ;
$mconfig['width'] = $w;
$mconfig['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$mconfig['source_image'] = 'uploads/watermark.png';
$mconfig['new_image'] = 'uploads/images/watermark/watermark.png';
$this->image_lib->initialize($mconfig);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Comment: Did you install gd library?

Comment: Yes @DenizB. and its working only when I set the  Height value

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Height also

for example

```
$config['height']       = 50;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but i want the height to be Automatically changed deepening on the width value

Comment: Yes I know but putting Height value is required even if you do not need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Imagine you need Width 1000px

$height = ($fdata["image_height"] * 1000) / $fdata['image_width'];
$resize_height = (int)$height;

$mconfig['width'] = 1000;
$mconfig['height'] = $resize_height; 
$mconfig['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$mconfig['source_image'] = 'uploads/watermark.png';
$mconfig['new_image'] = 'uploads/images/watermark/watermark.png';
$this->image_lib->initialize($mconfig);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Here `$fdata["image_height"]` is uploaded image height and  `$fdata['image_width']` is uploaded image width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$uploaded_data = $this->upload->data();

$w = $width / 4;
$config['width'] = $w;
$config['height'] = round($uploaded_data['image_height']/($uploaded_data['image_width']/$w), 2);

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = 'uploads/watermark.png';
$config['new_image'] = 'uploads/images/watermark/watermark.png';
$config['quality'] = "100%";
$config['maintain_ratio'] = true;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
if ($this->image_lib->resize()){
    $this->image_lib->clear(); 
    return true;
}else{
    return $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```